# Application does not install in release mode when sent to server

Tags: php, android, mime-types

I have an instance in Amazon EC2 in which using PHP I upload an APK. I created a MIME-TYPE mapping `.apk` with `application/vnd.android.package-archive`, and also editing `.htaccess` by entering a type like this below:

```
AddType application / vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

The problem is that when I send a `.apk` in debug mode it works normally, but when I upload the application in release mode, it downloads correctly, however at the time of installation it displays a message that does not recognize the downloaded package.

To upload the file I use the `move_upload_file` method, like this:

```
move_uploaded_file ($ _ FILES ['fileUpload'] ['tmp_name'], $ dir. $ namefile)
```

Anyone have any idea what might be happening? Is there any other configuration that should be performed in the release mode so that it installs correctly? Do I need to do any specific in PHP configuration when sending the file?

Comment: Is the release version of the apk working in your physical device?

Comment: @NabinBhandari Is not working. I think it's something about signing. I'm just looking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the release version of your apk is working correctly in your device.

If it is working correctly, there might have been signature conflict in the server because of the old debug apk being installed there with a different signature. Try uninstalling the old apk from the server and install new one. If you cannot uninstall old one from the server, build the new release apk with a different package name and install it.